# How do I obtain copies of 1099-C forms from credit card companies?

Tags: united-states, debt-reduction, form-1099

I was supposed to receive 1099-C forms from credit card companies for forgiveness of some debt.

I have not received them (at a friends place, only 1 received), but unfortunately I am out of country. I do not have the numbers to call and ask them this information.

Is it possible to know what figures IRS has received from the institutions as 1099-C income for me?

Comment: Don't you know the amount of debt forgiven?

Comment: I do approximately. I don't want to mess up my return as IRS always checks a return first based on numbers.( income). Don't want to refile again if they reject it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get different transcript types .

https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Tax-Return-Transcript-Types-and-Ways-to-Order-Them

Comment: Updated the answer. Some might be available by phone and even online.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing a copy of a W-2 or 1099 form, the best way to get a copy is to ask the organization that sent you the form in the first place.  In this case, the best thing to do is to ask the credit card companies for duplicate copies of the 1099-C forms that they sent.

If you are unable to do this, you can get a copy of all the W-2 and 1099 forms that have been sent to you directly from the IRS by requesting a "Wage and Income Transcript" from the IRS.  To get this transcript, you need to submit [Form 4506-T](https://www.irs.gov/uac/About-Form-4506T) and check box 8.  According to [this page from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Tax-Return-Transcript-Types-and-Ways-to-Order-Them), the Wage and Income Transcripts for the current year (the one that just ended: 2015) aren't available until July.  Form 4506-T itself suggests that you might need to wait until next January to get the 2015 transcript.